# How to achieve this structure

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

I'm trying to create a word file with the following structure:

```
A. Heading 1
1.1 Heading 2
1.2 Heading 2
1.2.1 Heading 3

B. Heading 1
1.1 Heading 2
1.2 Heading 2
1.2.1 Heading 3
```

etc.
I've tried to modify the headings manually and set the numbering
and i've tried to set it via paragraph -> multilevel-list but neither of those two worked...

I can't really seem to get it right... :(
Can you please tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The headings belongs to the [basics](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/number-your-headings-HA010282072.aspx) of the MS Word knowledge:

- Click in the first Heading 1 heading in your document.
- On the Home tab, in the Paragraph group, click Multilevel List.
- Under List Library, click one of the styles that includes the word Heading or Chapter in gray text.

[image]

For example, click 1 Heading 1, 1.1 Heading 2, 1.1.1 Heading 3.

[EDITED]

To have A instead of 1. as Heading 1 just rename it:

[image]

Comment: Yeah... like I said in the question I've tried to set it like this, but it isn't the outcome I want. I want the prefix "A.", "B." etc. for Heading 1, "1.1", "1.2" etc. for Heading 2 and "1.1.1", "1.2.1" for Heading 3.. so it's a mixture of different styles

Comment: Just rename the Heading 1 after insertion to A - that's all!

Comment: Can you please upload your working version? If I rename Heading 1 to A then Heading 2 looks like this: A.1 Heading2

Comment: ah and the Heading 2 of B should start with 1.1 again :) thanks in advance

Comment: You are welcome: http://www.file-upload.net/download-9596687/Headings.zip.html